# graphql , understanding _ in resolve function in new GraphQLObjectType

Tags: graphql-js

what does mean '_' parameter in resolve function ?.  what is it  for ?

```
const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQuery',
    fields: {
        usersCount: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve: (_, args, { db }) =>
                db.collection('users').count()
        }
    }
});
```

where i can read documentation about resolve parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"_" it's just to assign anything, because this parameter will not be used.

```
resolve:    (root, args, context, info) => ...
```

Read more on:

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/844